# Javascript countdown to window close

Tags: javascript

```
$(function(){
      var count = 5;
      countdown = setInterval(function(){
        $(".countdown").html("Closing in " + count + "...");
        if (count == 0) {
          window.close();
        }
        count--;
      }, 1000);
    });
```

Doesn't seem to be working for me. But if I change `window.close();` to `window.location = "http://google.com";`, it works. Any help on closing a window after a countdown would be a great help!

Thank you!

Comment: You might read the description here and see if it applies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.close?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.close#Description Are you seeing that error in your console?

Comment: Hmm, I was testing this in a tab in Chrome. Didn't work. But when I pop up my own window (which my app does), and then fire this code in that window, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which browser are you trying  this ? Usually it is not that simple when working in browsers that have multiple tabs opened .. I used the below for opening and closing a window (single tab) and it worked for me

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I was testing this in a tab in Chrome. Didn't work. But when I pop up my own window (which my app does), and then fire this code in that window, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can not close windows that you did not make with window.open().

Would you want to go to some random site and all of the sudden your browser just closes? Most people do not want that so browser developers prevent it from happening. There are hacks that work, but most of the time browsers will fix those hacks and they stop working.

If you want to control it in a corporate environment, you can always have the user's run their browsers in kiosk mode.